# Format for varbinary in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

My database table contains a column `Image` with datatype `Varbinary(50)`, and I would like to enter the value to that column dynamically to the table, so what is the format for varbinary to enter the value to the `Image` column?

Comment: `varbinary` = binary data. Either you type out your bits and bytes directly (`insert into table(Image) values (0x1234567)`), or you have some kind of code handling the nitty gritty details for you...

Answer (score 0):

The varbinary column contains binary data. In order to insert binary data into a column you can stream it in with the various OLEDB/ADO drivers, defining the data as binary, or you can insert data into the column using binary notation.

For example, if I wanted to insert the binary value for "A" into the column, I need to insert this:

```
 CREATE TABLE Binarytest
 ( id INT
 , note VARBINARY(500)
 )
 ;
 INSERT BinaryTest SELECT 1, 0x41
 INSERT BinaryTest SELECT 1, CAST( 'A' AS VARBINARY)

 SELECT note, CAST( note AS VARCHAR) FROM BinaryTest

 DROP TABLE binarytest
```

Note that I am doing this two ways.